# перезаписать файл

Tags: python, бот, aiogram, rewrite

при работе этого кода на диске создается папка /photos куда загружаются картинки, отправленные пользователем, но мне нужен только один перезаписываемый файл.
как реализовать перезапись на диске загружаемого пользователем файла?

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=["photo"])
async def get_photo(message):
    file_info = await bot.get_file(message.photo[-1].file_id)
    await message.photo[-1].download(file_info.file_path)
```

Comment: Удаляйте текущий файл, если он есть и загружайте новый, в чём проблема?

Comment: нужно чтобы имя оставалось тем же

Comment: Удаляйте файл, если он есть, загружайте новый, дайте ему любое имя, в чём проблема?

Comment: это должно происходить автоматически. но я пока незнаю как

Comment: к тому же когда файлы загружаются, они именуются сами. проблемы в удалении конечно нет. но как именовать загруженный файл автоматически